# How would you scan an email for a key, perform a task once that key is found, and then completely exit the code once that task has been finished?

Tags: python, while-loop, gmail, exit, imaplib

Basically I am just trying to figure out a way to run certain processes while I am out of the office.  I want to just set up a quick template code by performing a fairly simple process (like restarting my printer).  The issue that I am having at the moment is that when I run this code I can't figure out a good way to kill the code entirely after the process has executed.

The code that I am using:

```
import imaplib
import time
import sys

user = '#my email'
password = '#my password'

server = 'imap.gmail.com'
mailbox = 'Inbox'
    




while True:

    try:
        imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server)
        imap.login(user, password)
        
        email_count = imap.select(mailbox, True)
        results, data = imap.search(None, '(FROM "#my email" SUBJECT "Test")')
        
        ids = data[0]
        id_list = ids.split()
        latest_email_id = id_list[-1]
        result, data = imap.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)")
        raw_email = data[0][1]
        print(raw_email)
       
        imap.logout


    except:
        print("no email found")

    
    
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Could you more clearly explain your problem?  What does the code do, and what would you rather it do?

Comment: You want `imap.logout()`.  `imap.logout` just finds the function, but does not call it.  If you want to quit the script, some thing like break or sys.exit() will shut it down.

Comment: So the script above is a test script.  I am trying to make the script recognize a command that shows up in my mailbox (in this case, an email from an alternate account that contains the subject "Test").  Once it finally detects an email from that alternate account that contains the subject "Test", I want the code to acknowledge that it has been found, and then entirely shut the script down.  But at the moment once it finds the "Test" email, it just infinitely loops, logging in and finding the email over and over again.  I can't get sys.exit() to entirely shut the script down for some reason.